# How do I resolve sigabrt error on codechef ide

Tags: c++, runtime-error, sigabrt, greedy

Sigabrt runtime error occurs of a fatal error, because of an assert statement not returning true? Or use of excessive memory, I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong here, help me out?

( problem 1343 C on codeforces) [link](https://codeforces.com/contest/1343/problem/C)
so here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int check(int i,vector<int> a) {
    if (a[i] > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) 
    {
        long int n;
        cin >> n;
        vector<int> a(n), b;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> a[i];
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n)
        {
            int max = a[i];
            int s = check(i,a);
            i++;

            while (i<n && check(i,a)== s) {
                if (a[i] > max)max = a[i];
                i++;    
            }
            b.push_back(max);
        }
        int s = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k< b.size(); k++) {
            s += b[i];
        }
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Concerning `int check(int i,vector<int> a)`: Your are passing a vector _by value_. That's completely unecessary and comes with a penalty in space and time. Try const reference instead: `int check(int i, const vector<int> &a)`.

Comment: wrong: not using a debugger, using a online ide instead of a local one. Code is always full of errors, you need to learn how to find and fix them, codechef wont help you with that

Comment: That very function is seemingly pointless. In actuality it always checks a single value against zero, which could *easily* be done inline at the source.

Comment: what input causes the crash? Probably you dont know, then finding input that causes a crash should be the first step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have debugged your code and also ***the modified code has been accepted for the above question***.

**Mistakes you made:**

**1.** In the below loop, value at *`i'th index`* of `vector<int> b` is being added to `long int s`. Instead, `b[k]` should be added to `long int s` because the ***variable being used in the loop is `k` not `i`.***

```
for (int k = 0; k< b.size(); k++) {
            s += b[i];
        }
```

**2.** In the question, range of `variable n` is given as *(1 ≤ n ≤ 2.10^5)*. So, it is safe to use `int n` instead of `long int n`. Also, when I submitted my code on codeforces it gave me *signed integer overflow error* when I used `long int n`.

**3.** You need to use `long long s` instead of `long int s` because the value of each element of array A lies between *(−10^9 ≤ a[i] ≤ 10^9 , ai ≠ 0)* and when we add the elements it can *easily surpass `int` and `long int` ranges*.

**4.** Although, the answer got accepted when I used `vector<int> a` in the function

```
int check(int i,vector<int> a) {
    if (a[i] > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

But as the user Scheff has said and is correct that it comes with a penalty in space and time, you should use call by reference i.e. *`vector<int> &a`*.

**Modified Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int check(int i, vector<int> &a) {
    if (a[i] > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) 
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        vector<int> a(n), b;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> a[i];
        }
        
        
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n)
        {
            int max = a[i];
            int s = check(i,a);
            i++;

            while ((i<n) && (check(i,a)== s)) {
                if (a[i] > max)
                max = a[i];
                i++;    
            }
            b.push_back(max);
        }
        
        long long s = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k< b.size(); k++) {
            s += b[k];
        }
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

**Screenshot of Accepted Answer:**

[image]